# Continuity and maxima and minima

Tags: continuity

Is $\sin (t)/t$ continuous at $t=0$? And also, if a function $f(x)$ is of indeterminate form at $x=a$, can it be continuous if $f(a)$ does not exist? Can a discontinuous function have a local maximum or  minimum?

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$, defined by $f=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is continuous everywhere except at the point $x=0$.  Although the limit of $f$ as $x \to 0$ is $1$, $\frac{0}{0}$ is strictly undefined and so $f$ cannot be continuous there.

However, one can remove the discontinuity by constructing a new function, let's call it $\bar f$ such that 
$$\bar f(x) \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin x}{x},  & \text{if $x\neq0$} \\
1, & \text{if $x =0$ }
\end{cases}
$$This new function is continuous at $x=0$ and is, in fact, differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks for replying to the question. One more query, Why cannot we have sinx/x as 1 at x=0 as the limiting value tends to 1?

Comment: That is the limit. But it is not the value. The value is undefined since $0/0$ has no meaning.  Only through the singularity removal process do we end up with a continuous function.  Please "Up vote" if this helped.